# How do I change the ownership of files backed up with Time Machine?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, time-machine

I have a Mac which was reinstalled from scratch, and the owner accidentally changed her username when installing it. Current user id is "Jane" but old time machine backups were made when her user name was "Jan".

Now, she can't access her old backups.

The obvious solution is to go onto her backup drive and change the ownership of the hierarchy from "Jan" to "Jane" but every time I try, I hit the "operation not permitted" wall. I tried fixing the ACLs before executing "chown", but I get "operation not permitted" for that as well:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /Volumes/SeagateBackupDrive
# cd Backups.backupdb
# ls -led .
drwxr-xr-x@ 8 root  _unknown  272 Sep 20  2014 .
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
# chmod -a "everyone deny chown" .

# cd "Jane's MacbookPro"
# ls -led .
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 root  _unknown  170 Feb 14 16:03 .
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
# chmod -a "everyone deny chown" .
chmod: Failed to set ACL on file '.': Operation not permitted
```

I've tried all sorts of things like modifying the "writeattr" permission or looking for the uchg flag, but so far no luck.

This is on a Snow Leopard machine.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites

Comment: I wasn't sure which site was appropriate for this question. Feel free to nominate one of them for deletion.